# How calculate ratio with the lagged values per group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
a<-data_frame(school= c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
            year=c(2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012),
              numberofstudents=c(3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,NA,2,4))
```

Firstly, I wanted to change all NA values to the average value of that variable for this group. So, instead of NA should be 2.43.

Secondly, I wanted to calculate a fourth variable, which is ratio of the lagged value of the school to the number of the students.

```
data <- 
  a %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarize(lag.value.ratio = lag(school, 1)/numberofstudents) %>% ungroup
```

Unfortunately, I have the following error: Error: Column `lag.value.ratio` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 5.
How to avoid this error and get the average group value instead of  NA?

Comment: Hi John, Did you see my question to your comment below? Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the mean value of the group to replace the NAs, I calculate 2.83 to be the mean for school 3. You are getting the error because you are using summarize, which wants to collapse the result down to the number of groups that you have (in this case 2). I believe what you want is a mutate.

EDIT: I an loading the libraries used below and making sure that the `lag` function that is used is from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)    
    a<-data_frame(school= c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                      year=c(2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012),
                      numberofstudents=c(3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,NA,2,4))


a %>% 
  group_by(school) %>% 
  mutate(numberofstudents = replace_na(numberofstudents, mean(numberofstudents, na.rm = TRUE)),
         lag.value.ratio = dplyr::lag(school, 1)/numberofstudents) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   school  year numberofstudents lag.value.ratio
    <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
 1      2  2011             3             NA    
 2      2  2011             3              0.667
 3      2  2011             3              0.667
 4      2  2012             2              1    
 5      2  2012             2              1    
 6      3  2011             3             NA    
 7      3  2011             3              1    
 8      3  2011             3              1    
 9      3  2012             2              1.5  
10      3  2012             2.83           1.06 
11      3  2012             2              1.5  
12      3  2012             4              0.75
```

Comment: I tried your code. and i have got the different result. (in 6th line, the value 0.667 instead of NA.

Comment: Did you copy the exact code? Did you do an `ungroup` before calculating the lag.value.ratio?